# "Could not find service em to bind to em-consumer" in SAP Cloud Foundry

Tags: sap-cloud-foundry

Now I am learning Cloud Foundry and I have followed the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YL2fWcgyZ0) for Cloud Foundry Application, but at the end of the procedure I got

> Could not find service em to bind to em-consumer

error when `cf push` in cmd prompt.

[image]

Can anybody help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that on [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YL2fWcgyZ0&t=4m38s) ***em*** service is mentioned as a prerequisite which should have been created in a previous video.

If I'm not mistaken, I suppose [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3z-vxC_ynU) is the one which is mentioned, service instance creation is on the 9th minute.